# Ubuntu reboots after shutting down AND does not let me turn the machine back on afterwards

Tags: boot, dual-boot, power-management, asus, bios

Ok - so, I am seeing some very weird behaviour from my PC, specifically after installing Ubuntu.

The first thing is:

- Whenever I shut down via Ubuntu, it instead reboots, bringing me back to the GRUB screen where I can choose if I want Ubuntu or Windows
- When I try to shut down again, this does work - however something else weird happens that I’ll get onto in the second part of the question.

Now, in regards to the above, I’m seeing online that disabling Wake-On-Lan in the BIOS fixes this, in my case (ASUS BIOS) this is apparently called Power On By PCI-E — however, this is already disabled on my BIOS, so I’m not sure how to fix this.

Now the second part of my problem:

- (I should mention this only happens when I shut down from Ubuntu, not Windows)
- When the machine does shut down, I observe the lights in my PC casing and they all turn off
- Last second, the light on the GPU flashes one more time, and the machine turns off
- However now, if I press the on button on top of my PC, the PC does not respond
- I now need to unplug the power supply, plug it back in, and THEN I’m able to turn on the PC

Anyone have any ideas with what’s going on and how I could fix this?

Additional info I didn’t add:
Ubuntu Desktop version: 22.04.2 LTS
Kernel version: 5.19.0-46 generic
Exact methods I am using:

- Turning off the PC using the power button on the top right of the Ubuntu desktop and then “power off”
- This reboots me back to the GRUB menu where I pick if I want windows or Ubuntu
- I load back into the Ubuntu OS
- I then try to power off again (same way as step 1)
- Powering off works, but now I can’t switch my PC back on by pressing the physical button on my machine.
- I need to unplug the power supply and then repeat the above step in order to do so

Comment: You've not provided any clues as to what Ubuntu product, what release of that product, nor if kernel stack options exist for your *unstated* Ubuntu system (*I've had some power off issues on old nokia hardware & kernel stack seemed to matter; also how it was turned off of which you gave no details as to methods used*).  The starting point as I see it hasn't been provided (ie. we don't know what Ubuntu product/release you're using, nor what [easy] options are available given we don't have that detail)

Comment: @guiverc yes you’re right; sorry - added these now, hopefully they help and give more detail/clarity on my exact situation